Create limited Tables from ForeignKey dependency map in SQLAlchemy ORM
I have the following code:
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine, Column, String,
                    Integer, Float, ForeignKeyConstraint)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (DeclarativeBase, relationship)


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Process(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'process'

    run_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    process_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    process_attrs = Column(String, nullable=True)


class ProcessWeekly(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'process_weekly'

    run_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    process_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    week = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    loss_factor = Column(Float, default=1.0)

    process = relationship(Process)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint([run_id, process_id],
                         [Process.run_id, Process.process_id]),
    )


class Location(Base):

    __tablename__ = "location"

    run_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[ProcessWeekly.__table__])

What this code creates is just the ProcessWeekly table. What I wish to create is, since, the ProcessWeekly table has a foreignkey constraint on the Process table, I'd want to create that as well. Location table doesn't have any foreignkey dependency, hence, I do not want to create it.
This is just a simple example to suggest 1 level of Foreignkey constraint. However, in my use case, it'll be multi-level dependency, i.e., Process table can itself has a ForeignKey dependency on some further level tables.
How can I modify my code to create all the tables suggested in argument of the Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[...]) and all the further downstream tables with foreignkey dependency?
I'm using sqlalchemy==2.0.25.

A few years ago I solved this problem similar to this:
for table in Base.metadata.sorted_tables:
    table.create(bind=db.connection(), checkfirst=True)

But you may not need checkfirst. This also may not work if you have circular foreign key dependencies.

This will also create tables like Location in my example which is what I don't want.

Ah, sorry, I missed that part. I don't think that SQLAlchemy supports something like this. You'd have to use e.g. networkx for this and create a network from the foreign key constraints. There you could easily select subgraphs. But this is a bit of work.

Or you build something yourself from these foreign keys. In either case you'd need to track down those constraints. I think they are defined in the metadata? Would have to debug it.
